# How to push elements to JS array according to a predetermined schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of ids that determines the desired order of elements, which looks like this:

```
var desired_order = [0,4,2,1,3,...]
```

In my case it is much longer, so performance is to be considered.

I also have an array of objects with those ids, like this one:

```
var objects = [{name:"cat",id:0},{name:"dog",id:1},{name:"bird",id:2},{name:"elephant",id:3},
{name:"giraffe",id:4},...]
```

I need to create a new array `var = objects_in_desired_order` where these objects will be in the order determined by the `desired_order` array.

How to do that efficiently?

The only way I can think of is a double `for` loop where it goes over all possible ids in chronological order and pushes them where they belong. I would use this method if I wouldn't have such big arrays of data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Turn your `desired_order` array into an object that maps the array values to the *index* into the ordering array, so 0 -> 0, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 1 -> 3, etc. Then when you sort you can look up the "id" value efficiently in that object to perform the sort comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your objects array into a map `id => object`:

```
let m = new Map(objects.map(o => [o.id, o]))
```

Then,

```
let objects_in_desired_order = desired_order.map(id => m.get(id))
```

BTW, stop using `var`.

Comment: How exactly will this impose the ordering? Is it just by the rules of map entry ordering? (and yes in this case I guess that's ok)

Comment: @Pointy: I interpret the question so that `desired_order` contains object ids, whatever they are.

Comment: Yes, me too, and your answer may be 100% correct, I just don't see how getting the id out of the map will give the desired ordering.

Answer (score 0):

First make an object that maps values to ordering keys:

```
var orderMap = desired_order.reduce(function(map, value, index) {
  map[value] = index;
  return map;
}, {});
```

Now you can use that in a sort comparator:

```
objects.sort(function(o1, o2) {
  return orderMap[o1.id] - orderMap[o2.id];
});
```

The comparator will return a result based on the index of the id key in the original desired order array. The example above will sort the original `objects` array, so if you want to do the ordering in a new array you could `objects.slice()` it and make a new one to sort.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same technique as gog's answer, but wrapped in a reusable function.

```js
const reorder = (xs, is, idx = new Map (xs .map (x => [x .id, x]))) =>
  is .map (i => idx .get (i))

const desired_order = [0, 4, 2, 1, 3]
const objects = [{name: "cat", id: 0}, {name: "dog", id: 1}, {name: "bird", id: 2},{name: "elephant", id: 3}, {name: "giraffe", id: 4}]

console .log (reorder (objects, desired_order))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```